# Jruby: using Pry with JRuby (and JRubyFx)

Tags: windows, jruby, javafx-2, pry

**What is the correct way to use Pry gem with JRuby and JRubyFx on windows?**

I am using the JRubyFx (a JavaFX JRuby binding - https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx) and for my test I am using this [example](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx/blob/master/samples/fxml/Demo.rb) shrinked to the minimum necessary lines.

```
require 'jrubyfx'
require 'pry'

class SimpleFXApplication < JRubyFX::Application
    def start(stage)
    stage.title = "jrubyfx app"
    @ctrlr = SimpleFXController.load_fxml("some_fxml_code_for_ui.fxml", stage)
    stage.show
  end
end

class SimpleFXController < JRubyFX::Controller
end

SimpleFXApplication.launch
binding.pry
```

After launching the app I the console is not accepting input anymore and "pry" only comes back accepting input when I close the SimpleFXApplication window.

I've also tried using Java Threads:

```
...
binding.pry
Java.java.lang.Thread.new do SimpleFXApplication.launch end
```

But then, although a new thread id is shown as running, SimpleFXApplication never starts.

Another thing I tried is starting pry from console and then requiring and launching SimpleFXApplication:

> jruby -S pry
>
> require './jrubyfx_demo.rb'
>
> true
>
> SimpleFXApplication.launch

And I receive the following errors...

> Exception running Application: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown
>   protocol: c java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
>   java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   org.jruby.javasupport.JavaConstructor.newInstanceDirect(JavaConstructor.java:291)
>   org.jruby.java.invokers.ConstructorInvoker.call(ConstructorInvoker.java:104)
>   org.jruby.java.invokers.ConstructorInvoker.call(ConstructorInvoker.java:197)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:211)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:217)
>   org.jruby.java.proxies.ConcreteJavaProxy$2.call(ConcreteJavaProxy.java:56)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:211)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:217)
>   org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:862)
>   org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)
>   org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrOneOrTwoOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:295)
>   org.jruby.java.proxies.ConcreteJavaProxy$3.call(ConcreteJavaProxy.java:155)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:346)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:204)
>   org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
>   org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
>   org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
>   org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
>   org.jruby.ast.AttrAssignOneArgNode.interpret(AttrAssignOneArgNode.java:33)
>   org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
>   org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
>   org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
>   org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:268)
>   org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:220)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:366)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:238)
>   org.jruby.ast.FCallThreeArgNode.interpret(FCallThreeArgNode.java:40)
>   org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
>   org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
>   org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
>   org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
>   org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225)
>   org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:204)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:346)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:204)
>   org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
>   org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
>   org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
>   org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
>   org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
>   org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
>   org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:188)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
>   org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
>   org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
>   org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
>   org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
>   org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:224)
>   org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:119)
>   org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
>   org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
>   org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
>   org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:209)
>   org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:197)
>   org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:128)
>   org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:89)
>   org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:261)
>   org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:213)
>   org.jruby.javasupport.JavaUtil$1.call(JavaUtil.java:237)
>   org.jruby.javasupport.util.RuntimeHelpers$MethodMissingMethod.call(RuntimeHelpers.java:445)
>   org.jruby.gen.InterfaceImpl1014569521.run(org/jruby/gen/InterfaceImpl1014569521.gen:13)
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   => nil

I am guessing it has something to do in how JrubyFx uses threads, or I don't know if it is a more generic issue that affects Pry usage with JRuby..
I'd like to know more, I'd appreciate if someone could share some advice.

Comment: Show the code you used, please.

Comment: thanks, I added code and better description of the issue.

Comment: What is the complete path to 'some_fxml_code_for_ui.fxml'?

Comment: Path was too nested for the example, so I moved both 'jrubyfx_demo.rb' and 'some_fxml_code_for_ui.fxml' in 'c:\example\app', and ran the same code from there, but I had the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleFXApplication.launch never returns until the Platform.exit is called (closing the windows does this in the background)

To do what you are trying to to, fork off in the start method, or in some other timer method once JavaFX has launched the application.

As one of the JRubyFX developers, I can also tell you how threading works in JRubyFX/JavaFX:

1. main thread spawns the UI JavaFX thread and waits on a lock from the JavaFX thread
2. UI thread launches a bunch of Platform stuff
3. UI thread calls start(stage)
4. start(stage) sets up event handlers, UI, etc (this is where you should launch pry)
5. user calls stage.show to start JavaFX events (click, mouse move, keypress, minimized, etc)
6. event thread calls back to UI thread with the event handlers
7. User signals via clicking the [x] or calling Platform.exit that they want to close JavaFX
8. stage.show receives event lock and returns
9. UI thread releases lock on main thread.
10. UI thread cleans up while main thread continues

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this:

Exception running Application: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c java.net.URL.(Unknown Source) java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)

Do you have something in your configuration file that specifies file locations?  If so, what is the value there?

If you're using "C:[something]", and C is your current drive, I'd suggest trying removing the "C:" in case pry is getting confused by the drive letter.

-- Keith